# Should I remove previous version of software before install new one?

Tags: software-installation, slackware

I have installed qemu by slackbuild. Now I want to install newer version of it from official website. Is it necessary to remove the old one before install the new version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're mixing a package that was provided by slackbuild with one that comes from the official website I'd be inclined to remove the previous package first. Then install the official one.

Prior to doing the removal, I'd make a backup of any configuration files just so that you have them as a reference prior to doing the new install.

Comment: depending on package manager, you can remove certain packages without removing the config files.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal - Yeah I wasn't sure how to broach that topic with the OP. I found this link which covers their use: http://www.slackware.com/~mrgoblin/slackwaretools.php